# <object> element, data source requested three times per page request?

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Tested with IE9 and Firefox, problem does not occur in Firefox.

I am using

```
<object data="/generatepdf/docid=23" width="960" height="1360"></object>
```

to embed a pdf, and when I break into the server code of the generator or check the weblog, I can see that the data url is always being called exactly three times for one single request - generating the same pdf three times.

When I replace the same thing with

```
<iframe src="/generatepdf/docid=23" width="960" height="1360"></iframe>
```

then I do not get this weird effect. But I like the way  displays better, no scrollbars and the pdf seems to get more control (a toolbar that appears on mouseover), plus the iframe sometimes overlaps with an autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is here (Pete's comment):

[MVC Filestream Multiple Calls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8415661/mvc-filestream-multiple-calls)

IE's behaviour is "by design", it first wants to determine the content type (which can be easily caught on the server by checking if the useragent = "contype" and then returning the document without data), then it loads the document once more just for the smell of it (or at least I was not yet able to determine how to get rid of this second get - the referrer is changing, that might be helpful) and then finally the third call loads the document. KB documents this behaviour for up to IE 5.5, but I am seeing the same in IE 8 + 9.

Answer (score -1):

If your only concern is the way the PDF file is opened then you may use the PDF Open Parameters to change Adobe PDF Plugin behavior like so:

```
http://example.org/doc.pdf#Chapter6
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3&zoom=200,250,100
http://example.org/doc.pdf#zoom=50
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=72&view=fitH,100
http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=none
http://example.org/doc.pdf#pagemode=bookmarks&page=2
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=3&pagemode=thumbs
http://example.org/doc.pdf#collab=DAVFDF@http://review_server/Collab/user1
http://example.org/doc.pdf#page=1&comment=452fde0e-fd22-457c-84aa-2cf5bed5a349
http://example.org/doc.pdf#fdf=http://example.org/doc.fdf
```

you can find more information here http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf